# 'pubnub-react' does not contain a default export

Tags: reactjs, npm, tic-tac-toe, pubnub

I am following tutorial about TicTacToe in react with PubNub and when I tried to start it it says pubnub-react does not contain a default export. Any ideas why is that?

Thanks in advance!

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ORFW.png)
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiQ0x.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJrKn.png)

Comment: Please attach the full error log you are getting while running the app.

Comment: I just did it, you can see it as picture. Thanks!

Comment: Is it not possible to just add that as text in your post? Much easier to analyze that way. And redact your pub/sub keys, too, so that others don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right, `pubnub-react` haven't default export.

You can use it in 2 way

**First**

Using `Destructuring Assignment`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```
import { PubNubProvider, usePubNub } from 'pubnub-react';
```

```
import React from 'react';
import PubNub from 'pubnub';
import { PubNubProvider } from 'pubnub-react';

const pubnub = new PubNub({
  publishKey: 'myPublishKey',
  subscribeKey: 'mySubscribeKey',
  uuid: 'myUniqueUUID'
});

function App() {
  return (
    <PubNubProvider client={pubnub}>
      <Chat />
    </PubNubProvider>
  );
}
```

**Second**

export all module into `one` using `import * as <NAME>`

```
import * as PubNubReact from 'pubnub-react';
```

```
import React from 'react';
import PubNub from 'pubnub';
import * as PubNubReact from 'pubnub-react';

const pubnub = new PubNub({
  publishKey: 'myPublishKey',
  subscribeKey: 'mySubscribeKey',
  uuid: 'myUniqueUUID'
});

function App() {
  return (
    <PubNubReact.PubNubProvider client={pubnub}>
      <Chat />
    </PubNubReact.PubNubProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advices, but I am not really sure about how exactly should I do it.
I was following this tutorial - https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-a-multiplayer-tic-tac-toe-game-in-react/#

Any recommendations?
Edit:
Also added pictures of my current code :)

Comment: just replace that import with import { PubNubProvider, usePubNub } from 'pubnub-react';